# Flask + Ajax calls "randomly" fail as user is not authenticated

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask, heroku, flask-login

I have a Flask application running on Heroku, with python waitress WSGI server.

In one page, there are 9 Ajax calls to the same Flask view (each call with different parameters) returning a JSON object. The view requires the user to be authenticated: I use the `@login_required` decorator and the `current_user` proxy of flask-login extension to this end.

**Flask view**

```
@dashboard.route('/_dashboard_std_summary', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def _dashboard_std_summary():
    """ Return the data for the dashboard """
    param = request.get_json()
    # executes a query using the id of the logged in 
    # user (current_user.id) and some data passed with 
    # the request, and builds a dict called data
    ...

    return jsonify(success=1,
                   data=data)
```

**Ajax call (one of the nine)**

This code is part of a template that is included 9 times in the main page. The `widget_field_id` is unique and passed to each template (perhaps not the best architecture, but it works locally).

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
        url: "{{ url_for('dashboard._dashboard_std_summary') }}",
        data: JSON.stringify({widget_field_id: '{{ widget_field_id }}',
                              status: '100'
                          }, null, '\t'),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
    })
    .done(function(response){
            ... do something with the reponse ...
    })
```

Everything works fine locally on my machine, but when I upload on Heroku the problems start: some of these calls randomly fail (I literally mean it, randomly) with a 302 code, and instead of returning the JSON object the response contains the html code of the login page.

AFAIU, in some (random) calls, the user is not recognized as authenticated (although it is in the other calls), and the flow is redirected to the login page (that is why I see the login page html code in the response).

If I reload the page, not always the ajax calls fail, but when they do, not always the same calls fail. In the following image, you can see that 5 out of 9 calls failed, returning 302.

[image]

I am confident the problem is not in the view.

I am going crazy with this. Any suggestions about where to look to identify the problem?

Comment: Could you provide the Ajax calls too? I think it's related to the async nature of Javascript.

Comment: @MihailFeraru I have added the ajax call.

Comment: It seems something related to session...